# Telebot не редактирует сообщение

Tags: python, telebot

Бот выдаёт ошибку что-то вроде message can't be edited. Не могу понятьв чём проблема.

```
 def except_func(message, call):
        except_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        exept_back_butt = types.InlineKeyboardButton('К списку заданий', callback_data='find_butt')
        exept_again_butt = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Попробовать ещё раз', callback_data=call)
        except_markup.add(exept_back_butt, exept_again_butt)
    
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка. Возможно данные введены неверно', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=msg.chat.id, message_id=msg.id, text ='gh', reply_markup=except_markup)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй
UPD1

```
    except_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    exept_back_butt = types.InlineKeyboardButton('К списку заданий', callback_data='find_butt')
    exept_again_butt = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Попробовать ещё раз', callback_data=call)
    except_markup.add(exept_back_butt, exept_again_butt)

    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка. Возможно данные введены неверно')
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=msg.chat.id, message_id=msg.id, text='gh', reply_markup=except_markup)
```

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало

Comment: А если теперь??